Muffled audio when in a call
On my phone I have noticed that when in a call (and it doesn't matter which app you use), my audio gets very muffled, as if the phone tries to do some heavy noise canceling, but with audio coming from itself for some reason (i am using headphones and there is no way it hears the sound bleeding from them)... I can only hear the most loud sounds from any other app and it clearly "chops" it too, but the call is crisp and clear. This must be some king of Android feature that helps you focus of the call, but I couldn't find it in settings. Any ideas?

The headphones are connected via Bluetooth? If yes then may be the phone switches the Bluetooth profile from normal audio profile to handsfree profile. To my knowledge the first provides good audio quality but lacks microphone support and the latter supports microphone audio in but only supports low quality audio.

@Robert, yes, the headphones are bluetooth, but won't this thing make the calls worse quality too? As I said, the call itself is flawless, it is the other apps's sounds that are messed up

The common call quality in cellular networks is already that bad that you won't hear a difference in handsfree profile. Or are you talking about calls in third party apps like Zoom, Teams and so on? They use a better quality but still far away from quality used by songs and other audio tracks.

If you think it "helps you focus on the call", then the feature is usually called "audio ducking," though it shouldn't muffle the audio, only lower the volume. However, muffling audio and using headphones reminded me of the same problem I had on Google Meets for Web: forced mono audio (on Android, this usually can be found on Accessibility settings)
